# XLookup with an IF Statement to return an Empty String if Value Not Found

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

Right now, when I do an XLOOKUP, if a value is not found, `0` is returned.

What I want to do is return an empty string if a value is not found.

What I am doing so far is this:

```
IF(XLOOKUP(A2,DD,EE)=0,'',"Yes")
```

Yes is just my test value to make sure it is working.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ah, it seems I should have used double quotes instead of single. That was the answer.

```
IF(XLOOKUP(A2,DD,EE)=0,"","Yes")
```